# Force LSTM Keras to use time series dependencies

Tags: python, time-series, keras, lstm

I have two time series A and B:

```
A: 1,2,3,1,2,3,3,3,1,2,3,3,3  
B: 0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1
```

This simple training set says that signal B is correlated to A. In fact each time A is equal to 3, at the same time stamp, in B, the value is 1.

I introduced the example above just to explain my problem. When I forecast data by using LSTM with Keras, I want the model understands this kind of dependencies from series.

Now I use this configuration:

```
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(hidden_nodes, activation='sigmoid', input_dim=num_features, input_length=window, consume_less="mem"))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(num_features, activation='sigmoid'))

optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=learning_rate, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
```

But I see LSTM forecasts value without apparently use dependences between time series. If I make a prediction with a window of 5, in order to forecast the next point:

```
A: [1,2,3,1,2]
B: [0,0,1,0,0]
```

I expect that LSTM gives me value 3 for A and 1 for B, because the training set below says that.

The problem is that my net seems use the signals without give the right weight to signals dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have only one series with two features.

If A and B are lists (not numpy arrays):

```
fullSeq = np.array(A + B)
#this shape is (lenA + lenB,)

fullSeq = fullSeq.reshape((2,len(A)))
fullSeq = fullSeq.swapaxes(0,1).reshape((1,len(A),2))

#make sure that the resulting array is something like [[[1,0],[2,0],[3,1],...]]
```

Now you have a single sequence with `num_features=2`. A and B get totally dependent now.

Comment: I do, but it is related to signals dependencies?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Ok, I try to explain it better. Also if I do what you wrote above, it seems the network doesn't takes into account with dependencies between signal A and signal B.
For instance I can't use a regression algorithm on B (or A), because they are correlated.

Comment: This approach treats A and B as the left and right channels of an audio signal, for instance. When you put them together (as the input) like that, they will be together until the end of the model. You can use any regression algorithm, and this regression will work on both sequences at the same time.